# Most efficient way to remove particular dates (29 Feb) from time series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas DF with c. 160k dated observations over 10 years, and want to remove all those from 29 Feb in leap years to enable consistent day on day comparisons across all years.

df column with timestamps (created using pd.to_datetime) is 'Dates'.

I have used the following to create month and day columns

`df['month'] = temp_data.Date.dt.month
df['day'] = temp_data.Date.dt.day`

and the the following to create a boolean mask for 29 Feb dates:

`df['leapday'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['month'] == 2 and x['day'] == 29 
                                       else False, axis = 1)`

And can easily filter df on this boolean mask. But on a df of 160k observations this is slow, and I suspect there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df['leapday'] = temp_data['Date'].dt.month.eq(2) & temp_data['Date'].dt.day.eq(29)
```

to drop Feb. 29:

```
temp_data = temp_data.loc[~(temp_data['Date'].dt.month.eq(2) & temp_data['Date'].dt.day.eq(29))]
```

there is also an attribute to check for a leap **year**:

```
DateTimeSeries.dt.is_leap_year
```

Comment: @MaxU Works perfectly (and very fast), thanks. I had tried exactly this mask but using '==2' instead of '.eq(2)', which didn't work. What's the important difference between '==' and '.eq()' ?

Comment: `mask = (df.is_leap_year == 1) & (df.dayofyear == 60)`

Comment: @Zero, thank you. I guess it will be slower to convert it to string and then compare strings...

Comment: @chrisrb10, as Zero has already mentioned you should put comparisons into parentheses because of Python's operator precedence...

Comment: @ScottBoston, very interesting approach! Please post it as an answer. It could be faster compared to mine... I'd right it this way: `mask = df.is_leap_year & df.dayofyear.eq(60)`