# Is it possible to insert a date without considering leap year day 29th Feb in leap year with pandas dataframe or any other means?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series of 65 year (1941-2005). I have inserted a date column in the dataframe as shown below:

```
Dataset= pd.read_csv('city10.csv', header = None)
Dataset['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1951', periods=len(Dataset), freq='D')
Dataset.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

This generates the following dataframe

```
Date         0       1       2       3  ...       5       6        7         8                                                                
1941-01-01  0.0  17.844  155.33  426.53  ...  61.102  47.929 -4.58980 -4.597900
1941-01-02  0.0  18.582  124.23  425.69  ...  70.191  51.980 -3.00210 -3.793400
1941-01-03  0.0  19.464  111.64  425.03  ...  74.315  56.936 -1.63070 -2.724700
        ...     ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...      ...       ...
2005-11-23  0.0  17.832  140.09  439.76  ...  63.003  49.942 -0.79576 -5.252300
2005-11-24  0.0  17.904  149.54  439.58  ...  58.072  47.666 -4.88510 -5.032600
```

The above-generated date generates 29th February in the leap year. I don't want to generate 29th Feb date i.e. for the series I want to considers 365 days in each year. It should not generate 29th Feb in a leap year.

Comment: If you're not going to consider the years as they actually occurred, when why use dates at all?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350416/11610186

Comment: Then why not simply remove all Feb 29 dates after data frame build?

Comment: @ Paul H I have a dataset from a model that considers 365 days in a year. After generating the date i will insert the month index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is generate `date_range` with longer length, then remove `29.2.` and assign to column by real length of `DataFrame`:

```
d = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1951', periods=len(Dataset) + int(len(Dataset) // 365), freq='D')
d = d[(d.month != 2) | (d.day != 29)]

Dataset['Date'] = d[:len(Dataset)]
```